# Development and production versions of wiki-article (MediaWiki CMS)

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to realize few versions of wiki-article (using MediaWiki CMS) — development version and production version and simple way to switch versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FlaggedRevs extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlaggedRevs) does something similar.